Use helicoil in tight space
I messed up one of the threads on my transmission, where the shaft's cover is connected. I want to retap it using helicoil. The only problem is that the hole is in the corner and I can't use my drill to get to it in a full straight line.
-------  
| x
|
|  ^
|  | 
|

The reason for this is because the head of the drill, where the drill bit goes into, is a bit too thick.
What would be a good solution for this? I tried to find long drill bits for this size (8.3mm), but couldn't really find a good one.

Are you saying that if you had a longer drill bit, that you would then have room?

Yes, exactly. The longer drill bit, maybe 15-20cm would be enough.

Do you have a welder?  I have extended a drill bit by welding a it onto a steel rod.

You could try a drill bit extension. It is similar to a regular ratchet extension but has set screws to hold the bit in place. It may help to grind a flat spot on the side of the bit so the set screws have a surface to bite into

Could you recommend one? I tried to use one, which has an SDS Plus "ending", but that doesn't fit into my normal drill. Also, it's difficult to find one for the 8.3 mm drill (as they are usually "normal" size).
